# Does IE6 skip over errors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I have got a javascript function, in side it there is this if statement

```
if (validate(document.SearchForm)) {
   document.SearchForm.action.value = action;
   document.SearchForm.submit();
}
```

it works fine in IE6 but not in firefox. it seems that firefox can not get past the arguement of If.

say for example the validate() function is none existant in my source, would IE go into the if statement? because that's what i'm starting to think since validate() isnt defined in the source at all.

Comment: is IE6 set to display an alert with Javascript errors? If not, it might be passing right over it

Comment: "Errors should never pass silently. Unless explicitly silenced." -- The Zen Of Python. Bow to its wisdom ;)

Comment: there is no error and the browser is not configured differently. is there a primiative function in javascript called validate()? i dont see how validate() could be working if its not definied in the code

Comment: Firefox is almost certainly behaving correctly, vs IE6. BTW, IE6 has just about dropped off the radar since the start of the year. Are you being forced to support it for some reason?

Comment: What do you mean by "works fine"? Believe me, if you don't have function called "validate" the if block won't execute - no matter what browser is used..

Comment: where in the "source" are you looking. try and check all the javascript that is linked in the page

Comment: Yes you're right there is a validattion.js which has validate()

Comment: IE 6 does break (in scope) on errors. If this isn't happening, an error isn't occurring. So if you are indeed including a script which defines the `validate` function, one of two things is happening: *either* there is a previous error in Firefox which prevents the definition of `validate`, *or* there is some kind of a race condition where the script calling `validate()` in Firefox executes before the definition of `validate`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, will work assuming "action" is name of some form element:

```
document.forms["SearchForm"].elements["action"].value = action;
document.forms["SearchForm"].submit();
```

Good practice is to not name form elements with reserved words like action or submit, but if you do so, use the `elements` collection like the above example.